# How to generate a date for the given time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

Using VB.NET and SQL Server 2005

I want to generate a date according to the given Outtime,

Am entering the value like

```
ID  Date       Intime   Outtime  Holiday

001 23-02-2009 08:00:00 17:00:00 no
001 24-02-2009 17:00:00 08:00:00 no
001 25-02-2009 10:00:00 16:00:00 no
001 26-02-2009 18:00:00 20:00:00 no
001 27-02-2009                   yes
```

Expected Output

Table1

```
ID  Date       Intime   Outtime  DateIn     Dateout

001 23-02-2009 08:00:00 17:00:00 23-02-2009 23-02-2009
001 24-02-2009 17:00:00 08:00:00 24-02-2009 25-02-2009
001 25-02-2009 10:00:00 16:00:00 25-02-2009 25-02-2009
001 26-02-2009 18:00:00 20:00:00 26-02-2009 27-02-2009
001 27-02-2009     -        -        -         -

…,
```

From the above table, DateIn column value should display same date column value, But Dateout column should display according to the Outtime.

```
In a first row – Intime is 08:00:00 and Outtime is 17:00:00, So Dateout should display the same date
In a second row – Intime is 17:00:00 and Outtime is 08:00:00, So DateOut should display the next day date.
In a third row – Intime is 10:00:00 and Outtime is 16:00:00, so Dateout should display the same date
In a fourth row – Intime is 18:00:00 and Outtime is 21:00:00, so Dateout should display the next day date.
In a fifth row – Holiday column value is yes, so it should not display any value in DateIn and DateOut
```

Dateout column should compare the Intime and Outtime value, if Outtime is less than Intime, Dateout column should display the next day date.

If Holiday = Yes then It should display as a blank column

For the above condition, How to make a sql query?

Whether it is possible in vb.net, which is faster sql query or vb.net code?

Need SQL Query or VB.NET code for the above condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work (note that my dates are in US format, since that's where I am :-) ):

```
create table times
   (
   Id             integer,
   stDate         datetime,
   InTime         datetime,
   OutTime        datetime,
   Holiday        varchar(3)
   )
go

insert into times values (001, '02-23-2009', '08:00:00', '17:00:00', 'no')
insert into times values (001, '02-24-2009', '17:00:00', '08:00:00', 'no')
insert into times values (001, '02-25-2009', '10:00:00', '16:00:00', 'no')
insert into times values (001, '02-26-2009', '21:00:00', '20:00:00', 'no')
insert into times values (001, '02-27-2009', null, null, 'yes')
go

select * from times
go

select
   t.Id,
   stDate,
   InTime,
   OutTime,
   case
      when Holiday = 'no' then stDate
      else null
   end       DateIn,
   case
      when InTime > OutTime and Holiday = 'no' then stDate + 1
      when InTime < OutTime and Holiday = 'no' then stDate
      else null
   end       DateOut
from
   times t
```

Results:

```
Id         stDate                  InTime                  OutTime                 DateIn                  DateOut                 
---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- 
1          2009-02-23 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 08:00:00.000 1900-01-01 17:00:00.000 2009-02-23 00:00:00.000 2009-02-23 00:00:00.000 
1          2009-02-24 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 17:00:00.000 1900-01-01 08:00:00.000 2009-02-24 00:00:00.000 2009-02-25 00:00:00.000 
1          2009-02-25 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 10:00:00.000 1900-01-01 16:00:00.000 2009-02-25 00:00:00.000 2009-02-25 00:00:00.000 
1          2009-02-26 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 21:00:00.000 1900-01-01 20:00:00.000 2009-02-26 00:00:00.000 2009-02-27 00:00:00.000 
1          2009-02-27 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    

5 Row(s) affected
```

Comment: Suppose Intime is 18:00:00 and Outtime is 21:00:00. It means Outime is next day, so How to make a query for this condition.

Comment: That condition doesn't match any of your other criteria.  You know, if you are simply trying to find the ending date and time of an 8 hour shift you are sure doing it the hard way. If you know when a shift starts (start date + start time) - and you know it is an 8 hour shift,  just add 8 hours to the start time!  It will go to the next day as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.date_column,
       t.intime,
       t.outtime,
       t.date AS datein,
       CASE
         WHEN t.outime < t.intime THEN
           DATEADD(dd, 1, t.date)
         ELSE
           t.date
       END AS dateout
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE t.holiday = 'no'
UNION ALL
SELECT h.id,
       h.date_column,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL
  FROM TABLE h
 WHERE h.holiday = 'yes'
ORDER BY date_column
```

...but there isn't any way to know if the outtime is really spanning into the next day (or more).  IE: intime of 1800 and outtime of 2100 could mean the next day.

Comment: Exactly, For Example Intime is 18:00:00 and Outtime is 21:00:00. It means Outime is next day, so How to make a query for this condition

Comment: @Gopal: That's my point - there is no way based on the columns you've provided to know.  You'd be better to drop the date column, and use intime and outtime columns as DATETIME - only then would you know for sure.

Comment: If Intime and Outtime datatypes as a Datetime means, How it will change. Can you give some example or ideas?

Comment: @Gopal: Changing intime & outtime to use DATETIME dataype means you get date **AND** time in the same column - you'll **have** to specify the date associated with the outtime...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CASE statement to add a day when OutTime is smaller than InTime, or display a blank date when it's a holiday:

```
select case 
    when holiday = 'yes' then ''
    when OutTime < InTime then DateAdd(day,1,[Date])
    else [Date]
    end as DateOut
```

Comment: Suppose Intime is 18:00:00 and Outtime is 21:00:00. It means Outime is next day, so How to make a query for this condition.

Comment: There's not enough information in your table to make that decision, since it can be both a 3 hour and a 27 hour workday.